# Handling multiple nested asyncs

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am having an issue working with async methods - namely nested async.

I start off a background task:

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        ServerWorkers.WebServer server = new ServerWorkers.WebServer();
        await ThreadPool.RunAsync(workItem =>
         {
             AnotherSync.Get();
             server.Start();
         });
    }

    public static async void Get()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(route + "?" + GeneralTags.COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef)) //.Result)
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    ApplicationObject.PrintData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Print>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    evError(new Exception(String.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase)), ErrorTags.PRINT_GET);
                }
            }
        }
    }

internal class WebServer
{
    private const uint BufferSize = 8192;

    public void Start()
    {
        StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();

        listener.BindServiceNameAsync("8080");

        listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
            using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
                IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
                uint dataRead = BufferSize;
                while (dataRead == BufferSize)
                {
                    await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                    request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                    dataRead = buffer.Length;
                }
            }

            using (IOutputStream output = args.Socket.OutputStream)
            {
                using (Stream response = output.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    byte[] bodyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>");
                    var bodyStream = new MemoryStream(bodyArray);

                    var header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                                $"Content-Length: {bodyStream.Length}\r\n" +
                                    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

                    byte[] headerArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
                    await response.WriteAsync(headerArray, 0, headerArray.Length);
                    await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(response);
                    await response.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then my app acts a web server..  It does not exit out.

If I add this so I have:

```
  public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        ServerWorkers.WebServer server = new ServerWorkers.WebServer();
        await ThreadPool.RunAsync(workItem =>
         {
             AnotherSync.Get();
             AnotherSync.Get();
             server.Start();
         });
    }

internal  class AnotherSync
{
    public static event delError evError;
    private const string route = "/api/Print";

    static wsPrint.IPrint wsPrint = new wsPrint.PrintClient();

    public static void Get()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
            using (var response =  client.GetAsync(route + "?" + GeneralTags.COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef).Result)
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    ApplicationObject.PrintData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Print>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    evError(new Exception(String.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase)), ErrorTags.PRINT_GET);
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

then the application exists out.

I may be mistaken but is it because I am using nested async methods?

Comment: the idea of using ASync is so you can continue working while another process runs in the background which voids the concept of await as it pauses the thread while the Awaited function completes the main reason MS added it was that events were being triggered in the primary GUI thread this means that if you performed any intensive functions the entire GUI would stop responding until it was completed, moving events to support ASync processing allowed the GUI to continue running while running an event

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the Task class as this si the more user friendly wrapper added to threading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MikeT yes, I know all this.  I was not saying it was a bad thing. Also, before Async was around you could just use Threads and delegates (to update UI).. However, I was not asking why they are used as my original question says?

Comment: I prefer asking on this forum as I do not always find the MSDN sites that informative as they discuss EVERYTHING rather than a specific.  My example is quite simple?  So I guess you do not know either then..?

Comment: my point was that Most of the time having multiple layers of thread nesting isn't required. and if you are using await  then they are almost certainly not required as if you need to wait then you don't need to. in otherwords because you are Awaiting your Async calls you no longer processing asyncronously

Comment: @MikeT I shall look into what you have said. Thanks

Comment: Ah your useing the Windows Application Framework, not a straight .Net app. that may change things as the WAF is specifically designed to take away the ability to control the computer. is is do that its harder to make malware such as viruses. i'm not sure how that affects multithreading

Comment: sorry deleted that comment as i spotted that all your start is doing is adding a hander to the listerner, that means your start is fire and forget function the loop is on the listerner

Comment: @MikeT Yes, that is correct. I had posted the same question in different ways and marked it with the Windows IoT tag. I only got 1 person replying and all they said was: it was my code, I need to log things.. So out of desperation I dropped the WindowsIoT tag off to try and get some more suggestions :(

Comment: been through your code and i don't think the issue is in the code your are showing, your webserver isn't doing anything but assigning a listener to  the socket, the handler should probably be its own method as thats way too complex for an anonymous function. but i don't see any issues inside there assuming you are using the WAF correcly.same goes for the get command,

Comment: this leaves the Run command now if this us your primary thread then what you will have is create webserver, start webserver, exit. if its not your primary thread then there must be something that monitors the StreamSocketListener to check if its still running or else it will be garbage collect and the app will exit

Comment: @MikeT Hi, thanks for taking the time to help me. I have noticed other odd behaviour. I have posted to this forum this questions: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=125027&p=838387#p838387. The only entry point i the Run comman. This stuff is all new to me though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of what a thread should look like,

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    //has to be declared here to keep the handle alive and prevent garbage collection
    private ServerWorkers.WebServer server = new ServerWorkers.WebServer();



    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        //Start the server running no need for await as its an synchronous
        server.Start();

        //don't exit until work is compelted
        while(server.Running)
        {
            //give up processor and allow other work to occur while you are waiting
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    }

    internal class WebServer
    {
        private const uint BufferSize = 8192;
        private StreamSocketListener listener;
        public bool Running { get; private set;}= false;

        public void Start()
        {
            Lock(this){//prevent any other code interupting
                if(!Running )//prevent multiple starts
                {
                    listener = new StreamSocketListener();
                    listener.BindServiceNameAsync("8080");
                    listener.ConnectionReceived += listener_ConnectionReceived;
                    Running = true;
                }
            }
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            Lock(this){//prevent any other code interupting
                listener.Close();
                listener.Dispose();
                listener = null;
                Running = false;
            }
        }
        public void listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        { 
            //process data from listerner's event
        }
    }
}
```

Note i'm not using the Windows Application Framework so might be different there

Comment: Thanks - an improvement on what I had :). Will test it out now. thanks

Comment: Note you will need something to trigger the stop or the loop will never exit

Comment: OK, unfortunately, there are a lot of keywords that are not available to me inside Windows IoT like 'Lock' for example.  There is so little info about all this for this device. However declaring WebServer as a modular variable was definitely correct.. :)

Comment: i have found the example you were following http://druss.co/2015/06/raspberry-pi-2-create-c-background-application-on-windows-10/ so that section of the code is definitely correct, the  taskInstance.GetDeferral(); is the same as the         while(server.Running) element i had

Comment: I thought that might be the case, as i said i'm not using WAF but he full up .Net

Comment: never-mind - the upside is I am not totally thick :)

Comment: Issue has to be that AnotherSync.Get(); but  i have no idea what that AnotherSync is

Comment: oops - should have added that to my question.  sorry. will do so now